# Count features in polygon by using aggregate (virtual field)

Tags: qgis-3, aggregation

I have a points layer and a polygon layer. The points are placed randomly. Some are within a polygon, some are outside. I would like to write the amount of points inside each polygon as virtual field into it's attribute table. I know, the aggregate function should do the job, but it don't:

```
aggregate('dots','count','id',within($geometry,geometry(@parent)))
```

I get 0 as result in every (multi-)polygon.

[image]

Comment: Convert your original geometry from multi to non multi ...

Comment: Will you see if changing `'id'` -> `"id"` work?

Comment: Just tested your code 1to1 and its working fine (with single-polygons). Its also working with multipolygons, but of course, in your case if thats one single multipolygon, it will count 6 dots. So the issue must be something else..

Comment: converting the multi to a single polygon was working. No other changes were needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression works well with multipart polygons, whenever:

- The geometries are valid.
- Both layers have the same CRS.

Therefore, you need to check both.

---

About the `'id'` subexpression, the `aggregate()` function expects a field reference of the joined layer there, so `"id"` seems to be the correct one if you want to count not null *dots id*s. However, anything that is written in single quotes is going to be considered valid and all rows being counted regardless of the values of any field.